# GIT checkout tag points to wrong sha1

Tags: git

I have a repository HELPER and about 350 tags created on it.
I am on 'master' branch and want to checkout a tag for read-only purpose.

When i do checkout, it says it is pointing to some sha1 id which not the sha1 of that tag.

here is the snippet,

```
bash-4.1$ git checkout **HELPER_F62.3.REL**

HEAD is now at **7e04dfb**... *HELPER_OS4.1.35*

bash-4.1$ git show-ref **HELPER_F62.3.REL**

**d722076d24ec9d13d845094181f47801ca77b4ca** refs/tags/HELPER_F62.3.REL

bash-4.1$ git show-ref HELPER_OS4.1.35

2782a48d2044b0fc0aa60ecf2823967a2312e1dd refs/tags/HELPER_OS4.1.35
```

I do not want to create a new branch, and I am fine with the detached HEAD as i use this repo as a read-only repo.

Currently on git version `1.8.0-rc0`

Comment: Do you have a branch with the same name?  I've seen this issue a few times in the past, and it's been a name collision between a tag name and a branch name.  Can you post the output of `git ls-remote .`?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you have an annotated tag.  When you use `git checkout` to detach `HEAD` and get on the corresponding commit, you see the commit-ID rather than the annotated tag's ID.

You can see this with, e.g., `git show-ref --deref`:

```
$ git show-ref --deref master annotag
a430f6d91b98d382b8d96f6812fc2056a6e6f678 refs/heads/master
20e14672ee2253d38c1001179d8f17688d47059c refs/tags/annotag
a430f6d91b98d382b8d96f6812fc2056a6e6f678 refs/tags/annotag^{}
```

shows that branch `master` (which I tagged with `git tag -a annotag` to create an annotated tag) is where `annotag` resolves once de-referenced, even though `annotag` points to a separate git object.

(Lightweight tags point directly at commits, and are unchanged under `--deref`.)

#### Dealing with tags in shell scripts

If you just want to get the annotated tag's hash ID, or just want to get the target of the tag, use `git rev-parse`, like this:

```
$ git rev-parse annotag
2e79bc84c11eda5d73add5a9dfc6bf03c50c432d
$ git rev-parse annotag^{}
676699a0e0cdfd97521f3524c763222f1c30a094
```

Note that the `^{}` suffix means *follow the tag to whatever object it locates*.  If the tag locates a tree or blob object, rather than a commit, the hash ID you get from the above is that of the tree or blob.  If you want to be sure that it is a *commit*, use the `^{commit}` suffix notation:

```
$ git rev-parse annotag^{commit}
676699a0e0cdfd97521f3524c763222f1c30a094
```

If the commit points to some other kind of object than the one specified in the braces, you get an error:

```
$ git rev-parse annotag^{tag}
2e79bc84c11eda5d73add5a9dfc6bf03c50c432d
$ git rev-parse annotag^{blob}
error: annotag^{blob}: expected blob type, but the object dereferences to tree type
[more error messages, snipped]
```

These syntaxes ([syntaces? syntagma?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65541/plural-of-syntax)) are described in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) (q.v.).

Comment: All the tags in the repo are light-weight. Noticed that in this repo, there are only 5 commits when i do a `git log`.

on doing `gitk` from windows, it shows all the tags are attached to these 5 commits. Not sure how this has happened.

Also, I am still puzzled about how git is showing different sha1 id for the tag.

Comment: OK, that's puzzling.  What about `git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all`, do you get anything more sensible from that?